# Ignite private IP for syncronize and public ip for read

Tags: ignite

I have ignite cluster running on cloud, i want to use public IP for query and other things and private IP for sync within cluster (gossiping).

```
 <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
      <property name="addresses"> 
          <list>
              <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
              <value>[public ip]:port</value>
              <value>[public ip]:port</value>
              <!--<when enable private ip not accessible from outside>--->
              <!--<value>[private ip]:port</value>
              <value>[private ip]:port</value>-->
          </list>
      </property>
  </bean>
```

How should i utilize benefits of private ip ? as i can see huge spike in public bandwidth usage.

Comment: You should remove public IPs from this config entirely. How do you run queries? JDBC? Thin client?

Comment: @Max for running queries, currently i'm using ignite library in client mode, but when i have removed public IPs it was not accessible using thin client on Dbeaver tool

Comment: By "public" I hope you mean something like a VPN access to your office rather than open to the Internet as a whole?

Comment: @StephenDarlington Yes sir.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should:

- Configure Communication and Discovery to use private IP as local host.
- Configure ConnectorConfiguration/[ClientConnectorConfiguration](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-client-protocol) to use public IP where applicable.
- Use JDBC/Thin Client to access from outside.

Comment: Yesterday i have changed my XML config file, 4 nodes on private and one node on public IP so now data usage is less but still want to minimize it.

Comment: for running queries, currently i'm using ignite library(.jar) in client mode, but when i have removed public IPs it was not accessible using thin client on Dbeaver tool